# Spring application Could not load JDBC driver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jakarta-ee, jdbc

Why application is not able to read the class from the build path? I did added ojdbc6.jar in the build path of the application.

Now when I kept this jar in the WEB-INF/lib directory, it worked fine.
Can someone please explain why it was not read from the project build path.

Comment: Build path is available while your app is building, not at runtime!

Comment: Thanks Jens! Got it! :)

Answer (score 0):

When you add it on the build path in your IDE , it is used for compiling the code (if there is a dependency on it).

Unless you package this and deploy on the server , the server has no reference to these files that were used for compilation. When you place it on WEB-INF/lib and package it , the jar file is also packaged in your .war file that is deployed and hence at runtime you will not get a Class missing or Driver missing error.